# Difference between passing component to Route as prop and wrapping component in render function

Tags: reactjs, react-router

What is the difference between routing to a component like this:

```
<Route path="coolPath" component={MyComponent} />
```

or

```
<Route
  path="coolPath"
  render={props => <MyComponent {...props} customProp="s" }
/>
```

To this:

```
<Route path"=coolPath">
  <MyComponent />
</Route>
```

or

```
<Route path"=coolPath">
  <MyComponent cusomProps="cp"/>
</Route>
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

first you should read through this site:
https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Route

But to explain, there's three things going on here, the first two are examples of routing with previous version of `react-router` (before v5) and the third is `react-router` (v5 - current) recommended approach.

**1. Route with component**

```
<Route path="/coolPath" component={MyComponent} />
```

This type of route renders the single component passed to the prop. If an inline function is passed to the Route's `component` prop, it will unmount and remount the component on every render via the use of `React.createElement`. This can be inefficient, and passing custom props via this method is only possible via an inline function. React Router's authors recommend using the `render` prop as opposed to the `component` prop for handling inline functions, as shown below.

**2. Route with render**

```
<Route path="/coolPath" render={props => <MyComponent {...props} customProp="s" } />
```

Instead of having a new React element created for you using the component prop with an inline function, this route type passes in a function to be called when the location matches and does not unmount a component and remount a brand new one during rerender. It's also much easier to pass custom props via this method.

**3. Route with children as components**

```
<Route path="/coolPath">
    <MyComponent customProp="s" />
</Route>
```

This is currently the recommended approach to routing, the child components will be rendered when the path is matched by the router. It's also very easy to pass custom props with this method.

Keep in mind there is a fourth type, which is:

**4. Route with children as function**

From reacttraining.com:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Link,
  Route
} from "react-router-dom";

function ListItemLink({ to, ...rest }) {
  return (
    <Route
      path={to}
      children={({ match }) => (
        <li className={match ? "active" : ""}>
          <Link to={to} {...rest} />
        </li>
      )}
    />
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Router>
    <ul>
      <ListItemLink to="/somewhere" />
      <ListItemLink to="/somewhere-else" />
    </ul>
  </Router>,
  node
);
```

Sometimes you need to render whether the path matches the location or not. In these cases, you can use the function children prop. It works exactly like render except that it gets called whether there is a match or not.