# Why does Route with children as components cause Typeerror, but route with component does not?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm using "react-router-dom": "5.2.0". According to this [stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59256109/difference-between-passing-component-to-route-as-prop-and-wrapping-component-in) post and [blog](https://ui.dev/react-router-v5-pass-props-to-components) to pass props to a component from route all I need to do is simply pass it like so:

`` {caseManagement && <Route path={`${SPA_PREFIX}/cases/:caseToken`}> <CaseView sarReport={sarReport} /> </Route>} ``

However, when I do this my complier doesn't complain, but in my browser I get the following error.

```
CaseView.jsx:48 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'params') at CaseView (CaseView.jsx:48:1)
```

If I change the code to the following it works as expected.

```
{caseManagement && <Route path={`${SPA_PREFIX}/cases/:caseToken`} component={CaseView} />}
```

Of course in this implementation I'm not passing any props to it. How can I pass props to my component?
Below is the relative code of the component I'm passing props to

```
const CaseView = ({
  match: { params: { caseToken } },
}, sarReport ) => {
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issues

- ```
  <Route path={`${SPA_PREFIX}/cases/:caseToken`}>
    <CaseView sarReport={sarReport} />
  </Route>
  ```

  When rendering `CaseView` as a child you can pass any props you like, but the route props, specifically `match`, ***are not*** passed and the error occurs when accessing `props.match.params`.
- ```
  <Route path={`${SPA_PREFIX}/cases/:caseToken`} component={CaseView} />
  ```

  When rendering on the `component` prop, the route props ***are*** passed along, so `props.match.params` works, but now you can't pass the additional `sarReport` prop.

## Solution

In `react-router-dom` v5 to pass along the [route props](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/route-props) (*i.e. `history`, `location`, and `match`*) ***and*** other custom props you should use the [`render` function](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/render-func) prop.

Example:

```
<Route
  path={`${SPA_PREFIX}/cases/:caseToken`}
  render={routeProps => <CaseView {...routeProps} sarReport={sarReport} />}
/>
```

See [Route render methods](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/route-render-methods) for further detail and explanation between the different methods for rendering routed components.

Comment: Why is the {...routeProps} necessary? Why doesn't passing it like I did above work?

Comment: @London804 Because `component={CaseView}` doesn't allow for passing the additional `sarReport` prop to `CaseView` component, only the route props are passed along.

Comment: @London804 I added a bit more of this clarification to my answer.