# React component not showing on deploy

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

I created an website application with React, website looks fine in localhost, but once deployed to GitHub Pages one of the sections only appears when I refresh the page. The should section populate when the website is first visited not only on refresh. Home component contains Hero section and Cards section. [image]

[image]

Comment: Please post your actual code, not screenshots

Comment: There's a character limit, if I add my code I will exceed that limit.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to wrap the elements in the Route?

```js
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/about">
            <About />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/users">
            <Services />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/">
            <Home />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
```

Instead of calling it as a component property

**[Edit]**

If that didn't do the trick, I found another stack question that could be the same issue

[React Router not working with Github Pages](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71985764/14476782)

Comment: Thank you very much, I wrapped the elements in the Route instead of calling it as a component property. Why was this an issue / what's the difference between the two methods?

Comment: In short it is a difference in version. here is a stack answer on another question that also explains this somewhat in detail: [differences between component as prop or as child](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59256779/14476782)

Comment: Cheers, thank you for your help and references.

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no details to the context, I can assume that the path for the element might be off, as it's something that differs between localhost and remote repository.
If that's the case, make sure you have a relative path, rather than the absolute.

Comment: I have code for App.js added to my question , what do you mean the path for the element might be off. There should be no change from localhost to remote repository in regard to element path.